# Find all attributes which are number using lxml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath, lxml

I am using lxml with python 3.7 to parse a XML file.

I would like to iterate over all attributes in my XML which contains a number. This number could be a real or integer (e.g. 1, 5.2234).

Is there way to iterate over all those attributes using xpath? or anything else using lxml?

Short example:

```
<scenario name="ChangeLane_2" type="ChangeLane" town="Town01">
    <ego_vehicle x="107" y="133.5" z="0.5" yaw="0" model="vehicle.lincoln.mkz2017" />
</scenario>
```

Expected resolut would be the elements attributes: *x*, *y*, *z*, *yaw*

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a sample xml as well as the expected output from that sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with iterating over attributes selected by XPath, like `//@someattribute`, in lxml is it returns an _ElementUnicodeResult; not an object with properties like its name or parent.

For example, if you do this:

```py
print(tree.xpath("//@*[not(string(number(.))='NaN')]"))
```

you get:

```
['107', '133.5', '0.5', '0']
```

which are only the values.

I think what you'd have to do is iterate over the attributes after selecting the parent element and then try to see if it's castable as a number (float or whatever).

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<scenario name="ChangeLane_2" type="ChangeLane" town="Town01">
    <ego_vehicle x="107" y="133.5" z="0.5" yaw="0" model="vehicle.lincoln.mkz2017" />
</scenario>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

for elem in tree.xpath("//*[@*[not(string(number(.))='NaN')]]"):
    attrs = []
    for attr in elem.attrib:
        try:
            float(elem.get(attr))
            attrs.append(attr)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(attrs)
```

printed output:

```py
['x', 'y', 'z', 'yaw']
```